# Input não recebendo focus no clique

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte `script`

```
    function CampanhaDefault(origem) {
        $("#ValorMinimo").parent().parent().hide();
        $("#ValorParcela").parent().parent().hide();
        $("#PDesconto").text("% Desconto")
        $(".Juros").hide();
        $("#ValorMinimo").val(0);
        $("#ValorParcela").val(0);
        if (origem == "Novo")
            $(".vencimento").remove();
    }

    function CampanhaAlternativa(origem) {
        $("#ValorMinimo").parent().parent().show();
        $("#ValorParcela").parent().parent().show();
        $("#PDesconto").text("% Valor")
        $(".Juros").show();
        if (origem == "Novo")
            $(".vencimento").remove();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        CampanhaDefault("Inicio");

        $("#TipoCampanha").change(function () {
            if ($(this).val() == "2") {
                if (confirm("Os dados especificos da campanha tipo A serao perdidos. Continuar?")) {
                    CampanhaAlternativa("Novo");
                } else {
                    $("#TipoCampanha").find("option").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).val() == "1")
                            $(this).prop("selected", true);
                    });
                }

            } else {
                if (confirm("Os dados especificos da campanha tipo B serao perdidos. Continuar?")) {
                    CampanhaDefault("Novo");
                } else {
                    $("#TipoCampanha").find("option").each(function () {
                        if ($(this).val() == "2")
                            $(this).prop("selected", true);
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

O que acontece é que no meu `select` de tipo de campanha, quando altero para B (ou da B volto para A), todos `input` exibido em tela para de receber `focus` no clique.

Comment: posta o html ai também

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retirei o `confirm()` e funcionou.

O script ficou da seguinte forma:

```
   function CampanhaDefault(origem) {
    $("#ValorMinimo").parent().parent().hide();
    $("#ValorParcela").parent().parent().hide();
    $("#PDesconto").text("% Desconto")
    $(".Juros").hide();
    $("#ValorMinimo").val(0);
    $("#ValorParcela").val(0);
    if (origem == "Novo")
        $(".vencimento").remove();
}

function CampanhaAlternativa(origem) {
    $("#ValorMinimo").parent().parent().show();
    $("#ValorParcela").parent().parent().show();
    $("#PDesconto").text("% Valor")
    $(".Juros").show();
    if (origem == "Novo")
        $(".vencimento").remove();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    CampanhaDefault("Inicio");

    $("#TipoCampanha").change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "2") {
                CampanhaAlternativa("Novo");

        } else {
                CampanhaDefault("Novo");
        }
    });
});
```